# angular $save method fire a post request with wrong url

Tags: url, angularjs, resources, save

this is my service

```
album.factory('albumService', function($resource) {

    return $resource('/album/v1/album/:id', {id:'@id'})

});
```

however when I try to create an album

```
var newAlbum = new albumService($scope.album)
newAlbum.$save()
```

angular fires a post request to '/album/v1/album', which is wrong , it removes my trailing slash it should be '/album/v1/album/'.

because I'm using tastypie, without the trailing slash an error will rasie

```
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash
```

where is my trailing slash?

Comment: By default resource strip trailing slashes and set the url

Comment: then how can I add the  trailing slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably only two ways to get rid of the problem

1) Adding two forward slash and trailing slash at the end of url `\\/`(But it will not work in firefox)

2) Use traditional $http

Answer (score 2):

I used the workaround mentioned in the git issue thread, it works in firefox as well.

```
angular.module('ngResource').config([
    '$provide', '$httpProvider',
    function($provide, $httpProvider) {
        $provide.decorator('$resource', function($delegate) {
            return function() {
                if (arguments.length > 0) {  // URL
                    arguments[0] = arguments[0].replace(/\/$/, '\\/');
                }

                if (arguments.length > 2) {  // Actions
                    angular.forEach(arguments[2], function(action) {
                        if (action && action.url) {
                            action.url = action.url.replace(/\/$/, '\\/');
                        }
                    });
                }

                return $delegate.apply($delegate, arguments);
            };
        });

        $provide.factory('resourceEnforceSlashInterceptor', function() {
            return {
                request: function(config) {
                    config.url = config.url.replace(/[\/\\]+$/, '/');
                    return config;
                }
            };
        });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('resourceEnforceSlashInterceptor');
    }
]);
```

Comment: Finally an answer that works! Now I can try and get these dents out of the desk caused by me ramming my head into it angrily for the past 2 hours trying to cure this anti-feature.

Answer (score 0):

turns out this is a bug for django backend user

[Git issue list](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/992)

[Mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/taypgj_D3YQ)

Comment: This isn't an answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Now (as of Angularjs 1.3.0) you can just turn trailing slashes on: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource